# Graph.union summing edge weights attributes (igraph R)

Tags: r, igraph

I have 2 graphs, with weight labels:

```
library(igraph)

g1= graph.formula(A -+ B, A -+ C)
E(g1)["A" %->% "B"]$weight= 1
E(g1)["A" %->% "C"]$weight= 2
E(g1)$label= E(g1)$weight

g2= graph.formula(A -+ B, A -+ C, A -+ D)
E(g2)["A" %->% "B"]$weight= 10
E(g2)["A" %->% "C"]$weight= 20
E(g2)["A" %->% "D"]$weight= 100
E(g2)$label= E(g2)$weight

par(mfrow= c(2,1), mar= rep(0,4))
plot(g1); plot(g2)
```

[image]

When joining both with `graph.union()`, `igraph` by default creates `weight_1, weight_2` attributes.

**Problem:**

I want the joined graph to have edge weight attributes summed up. Applying existing [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762359/combine-two-graphs-and-add-edge-weights-in-r-igraph) is not optimal. 
First the solution does not scale well in case `graph.union()` creates many more `weight_...` attributes. Second it leads in case of the reproducible example only to a partial solution, as the edge `"A" "D"` contains no sum.

```
g= graph.union(g1, g2)
E(g)$weight= E(g)$weight_1 + E(g)$weight_2
E(g)$label= E(g)$weight
```

[image]

**Question:**

How can I recode to get finally following graph:

[image]

Comment: I am not looking for a manual solution (`E(g)["A" %->% "D"]$label= 100`), as I am handling lots of edges.

Comment: Have you checked out `?attribute.combination` yet? There is an option `sum` that could work for you.

Comment: I am aware of those but I don't see how they should help with graph.union. If you have a solution please post it as answer on the repeoducible example.

Comment: I think the easiest is to convert your graphs to data frames, do the joins, and then convert the result back to a graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Gabor's advise:

```
library(igraph)
library(intergraph)
library(dplyr)

# helper function
as.data.frame.igraph= function(g) {
  # prepare data frame
  res= cbind(as.data.frame(get.edgelist(g)),
             asDF(g)$edges)[ , c(-3, -4)]
  # unfactorize
  res$V1= as.character(res$V1)
  res$V2= as.character(res$V2)
  # return df
  res
}

df_g1= as.data.frame(g1)
df_g2= as.data.frame(g2)
df= rbind_all(list(df_g1, df_g2)) %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  summarise(weight= sum(weight))

new_graph= simplify(graph.data.frame(df, directed = T))
E(new_graph)$weight=  df$weight
E(new_graph)$label= E(new_graph)$weight

plot(new_graph)
```

[image]